# Tesseract 5.0.0-alpha box file format

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, training-data, python-tesseract

I was wondering if someone could give me a sanity check and verify my box file format.

I'm using the [text2img one](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/Make-Box-Files.html) per [the docs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html#creating-training-data), which orders the elements as `<symbol> <left> <bottom> <right> <top> <page>`

Every time I run this I get the `Bad box coordinates in boxfile string! 404 177 463 253 0` error for every set of coordinates, and the unicharset file is generated correctly.

The python/opencv code I am using to get the coordinates is as follows:

```py
brs = get_char_bounding_rects(img) # ordered bounding rectangles of characters (used in previous step to apply random transformations you can see in the image and regenerated after by a call to the same function)
if len(text) != len(brs):
    return
chars = zip(text, brs)
img_h = img.shape[:2][0]
for c, br in chars:
    x, y, w, h = br
    btm_left = (x, y + h)
    top_right = (x + w, y)
    btm_left_inv = (btm_left[0], img_h - btm_left[1])
    top_right_inv = (top_right[0], img_h - top_right[1])
    box_file.write(r'{} {} {} {} {} 0'.format(c, btm_left_inv[0], btm_left_inv[1], top_right_inv[0], top_right_inv[1]) + '\n')
```

which produces the following .box file:

```
K 26 26 92 100 0
- 110 56 168 60 0
9 191 25 242 101 0
2 259 24 311 103 0
K 327 28 389 98 0
R 402 29 460 97 0
K 473 23 543 103 0
V 549 28 608 99 0
- 623 56 689 60 0
6 710 28 757 98 0
7 780 29 824 97 0
E 842 26 899 100 0
9 916 27 965 99 0
6 985 28 1032 98 0
- 1059 57 1115 59 0
Z 1138 24 1192 102 0
1 1217 24 1250 102 0
L 1276 30 1323 96 0
U 1333 25 1404 102 0
```

and alternatively the full line:

```py
brs = get_char_bounding_rects(img)
if len(text) != len(brs):
    return
img_h = img.shape[:2][0]

top_extent = img_h
btm_extent = 0
for br in brs:
    _, y, _, h = br
    top_extent = min(top_extent, y)
    btm_extent = max(btm_extent, y + h)

left_extent = brs[0][0]
end_br = brs[len(brs) - 1]
right_extent = end_br[0] + end_br[2]

btm_left = (left_extent, btm_extent)
top_right = (right_extent, top_extent)
btm_left_inv = (btm_left[0], img_h - btm_left[1])
top_right_inv = (top_right[0], img_h - top_right[1])

box_path = r'path\to\training\tr\eng.romanc.exp{}.box'.format(index)
box_file = open(box_path, 'w')
box_file.write(r'WordStr {} {} {} {} 0 #{}'.format(btm_left_inv[0], btm_left_inv[1], top_right_inv[0], top_right_inv[1], text) + '\n')
box_file.write('\t' + r' {} {} {} {} 0'.format(top_right_inv[0] + 1, btm_left_inv[1], top_right_inv[0] + 5, top_right_inv[1]) + '\n')
```

and its .box file:

```
WordStr 26 23 1404 103 0 #K-92KRKV-67E96-Z1LU
         1405 23 1409 103 0
```

Here is the chain of commands I'm running, on Windows:

```
   python ./GenerateTrainingData.py
&& mkdir -p tr
&& cd tr
&& unicharset_extractor --output_unicharset eng.unicharset *.box
&& echo "RomanC 0 0 0 1 0" > font_properties
&& shapeclustering -F font_properties -U eng.unicharset -O eng.unicharset *.box
&& mftraining -F font_properties -U eng.unicharset -O eng.unicharset *.box
&& cd ..
```

and the corresponding image (but .png because I couldn't upload .tiff) below it, along with what I believe is supposed to be the way coordinates are defined as well as another way I've tried, where all numbers are distances from their respective image edge:

[image: generated text-string image]

[image]

[image]

(with y-inverted coords):

[image]

(full line):

[image]

[image]

[image]